# Need help with deleting second header so I am left with one. Magento 1.9 rwd theme

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, rwd-theme, rwd, header

[image]

If you look at the image within header.phtml there is a white block and a blue block. I want to completely delete the blue block so I am left with one header containing all of my header elements, that I can change to any colour I wish.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove that block completely then you should copy `template/page/html/header.phtml` from rwd to your theme and then remove following lines:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('accountLinks') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
```

This will make sure these blocks are not called.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked for me by commenting out the css for header language switcher and welcome message but your way sounds like it might be better. maybe i should just delete both the CSS and html for it